# Identifying the Redundant Requirements in Scrum

Tags: agile, scrum, requirements

I'm working on the research to resolve the Requirements conflicts in distributed Scrum where teams are distributed over multiple locations. I'm proposing a model that consists of five steps including identifying redundant requirements, removing them, assigning unique IDs to each requirement, storing requirement information and resolving requirement conflicts.
I want to ask that:

1. How Redundant requirements are identified in distributed Scrum?
2. How Redundant requirements are removed?
3. How unique IDs are assigned to each requirement?
4. How requirement information is stored?
5. and How requirement conflicts are resolved?

Comment: I am not an expert in "Scrum theory", but requirements in Scrum are stored in the Product and Sprint backlogs, and identifying redundancies and solving conflicts should be part of managing and refining those backlogs. That's the only thing which IMHO makes sense and should be quite obvious, so what's unclear to you?

Comment: I do not see a single problem in your question. It is the product owner's job to root out any conflicts or doubles in requirements before they even make it to a story. He does this by talking to his stakeholders.

Comment: I know that its the job of product owner but how he will perform all steps as in my problem?

Answer (score 2):

In Scrum, all of the requirements (and all other changes needed to the product) are maintained in the Product Backlog. The Product Owner is ultimately responsible for the content and ordering of the Product Backlog. The [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) is light on guidance for multiple teams, but there are lightweight scaled Scrum frameworks such as [Nexus (from Ken Schwaber and Scrum.org)](https://www.scrum.org/resources/online-nexus-guide), [Scrum@Scale (from Jeff Sutherland and Scrum, Inc.)](https://www.scrumatscale.com/scrum-at-scale-guide-read-online/), and [Large-Scale Scrum from Craig Larman and Bas Vodde)](https://less.works/). There are commonalities among these scaled frameworks - a single Product Backlog for all teams working on a single product and a single Product Owner who is ultimately responsible for this Product Backlog.

Regardless of the process or framework used, redundant requirements would be identified during the refinement of the Product Backlog. Ideally, the Product Owner and anyone supporting the Product Owner would be able to identify the redundant requirements before they are even added, but the refinement should be when the team identifies the redundant requirements.

In a complex system and for distributed teams, I'd recommend a tool for managing the Product Backlogs. This tool should allow for searching and other methods of categorizing items (such as tagging and labeling). This should improve the ability of the Product Owner and the people supporting the Product Owner to search both done and planned work to see if there are related or conflicting requirements.

The knowledge of the various development teams can also be used, but this is harder with both multiple teams and distributed teams, who may not have complete and in-depth knowledge of the entire system. The bulk of the work to manage the product and all of the requirements falls to the Product Owner and any product managers, analysts, or others supporting the Product Owner.

Regardless of who finds the conflicting requirements - the development teams, the product management staff, the Product Owner - the resolution is typically done through conversation, with the Product Owner having the final decision as to the Product Backlog and therefore the correct requirements for the product.

Scrum, or any of the scaled Scrum frameworks, doesn't call for any special handling of any conflicting requirements. There is no need to assign IDs to or do anything special.

Comment: 2nd point is how redundant requirements are removed once they are identified in product backlog. secondly i want to ask that which tool can be used to identify, remove, assign unique ids, storing requirements such as database?

Comment: @Aamir What do you mean how they are removed? If you're using paper sticky notes, throw it away. If you're using a tool, delete or close the item as a duplicate. As far as what tools to go, there are lots. Tool recommendations are beyond the scope of this site.